# Fail to connect my neo4j on centOS server by java driver

Tags: java, neo4j

I want to connect my neo4j database on centOS remote server by java driver.And I try to make neo4j traverse folder and insert every file into database.The code shows below:

```
package neo;

import org.neo4j.driver.v1.*;

import java.io.File;

public class HW {
    Driver driver;
    public HW(String uri, String user, String password) {
        driver = GraphDatabase.driver(uri, AuthTokens.basic(user, password));
    }

    private void addCompany(String name) {
        // Sessions are lightweight and disposable connection wrappers.
        try (Session session = driver.session()) {
            // Wrapping Cypher in an explicit transaction provides atomicity
            // and makes handling errors much easier.
            try (Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction()) {
                tx.run("call apoc.load.json(\"file:///home//ddd//data//shanghai//"+name+"\")yield value as company " + 
                        "create(c:company) " + 
                        "with c,company " + 
                        "unwind company.organizationInformationList as a " + 
                        "set c = a "                            
                        );
                tx.success(); 
            }
        }
    }
    public void close() {
        // Closing a driver immediately shuts down all open connections.
        driver.close();
    }
    public static void main(String... args) {
        File file = new File("/home/ddd/data/shanghai");
        File next[] = file.listFiles();
        HW example = new HW("bolt://202.112.113.71:7687", "neo4j", "rucer2017");
        String CompanyName = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < next.length; i++) {
            CompanyName=next[i].getName();
            example.addCompany(CompanyName);
            System.out.println(CompanyName);
        }
        example.close();
    }
}
```

And the code can't works. The error is:

```
org.neo4j.driver.internal.logging.JULogger info
信息: Driver instance org.neo4j.driver.internal.InternalDriver@23ceabc1 created
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at neo.HW.main(HW.java:129)
```

I have spent much time to fix it and failed. Moreover,the code works on my local Windows version Neo4j Desktop.Could anyone can help me? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like "/home/ddd/data/shanghai" is not the path of a directory on the machine running this code. If that directory does not exist, then `file.listFiles()` will return `null`, and the attempt to dereference `next.length` will throw a `NullPointerException`.